# add details to user profile( query that inserts logged in user and current gig into new table)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Ok guys, I am building a prototype ticket system where I have user profiles

`<li><a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?>">Profile</a></li>`

a users details are stored in `users table in my database.

I also have a gig table called `bands`. I show the bands with this code

**Band code**

```
    <?php
require 'core/init.php';


$Band_id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bands WHERE Band_id = $Band_id");

echo "<table border = '1'>
<tr>
    <th>Band Name</th>
    <th>Venue</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Add</th>
</tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Venue']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Category']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Stock']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><button>Buy Ticket</button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";


?>
```

I have just made a new table called `orders`. with two rows, band_id and user_id.

**question**

how can I build a query that would insert the band id from the current band and the current logged in user to the table `order` so I can use it later? (insert on button click)

Any help will be fantastic as I am rather stuck, Thank you.

```
Im thinking Insert `$Band_id` and `$user` in to `order` table.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use hidden field for brand id in your form like this:
you should use form for this.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><form name=\"myform\" action=\" something.php\"  method=\"post\">";
       echo "<td> <input name=\"brand\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"". $Band_id."\" ></td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Venue']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Category']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Stock']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><button>Buy Ticket</button></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=\" submit\" value=\"Buy Ticket\"></td>";
        echo "</tr> </form>";
    }
```

and use session for saving user id. after submitting the form get values from form and insert it your order table.

in your **something.php**

```
session_start();
$brand_id = $_REQUEST['brand'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

 $sql = "insert into order (brand_id,user_id) values($brand_id,$user_id)";
// then execute this query
```

i think it will work :)

Comment: Thank you Awlad Liton I will try to implement this suggestion, and get it to work. looks like the idea I was going for just did not know how to code it.

Comment: i will post my answer shortly

Comment: Will do in a min, just trying to connect the form button to the sql query.

Comment: should brand_id be Band_id ? also with the sql query dose it get the data for user_id and Band_id ?. sorry for the questions just trying to work it out so i can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function called lastInsertValue to get the id of the last inserted band. The user id, you can save it in session or you can make a query to get the user row searching it by the user name (I recommend you to do the first, save the user information in session).

Comment: Hmm that sound good, ok I will look in how to do this, possibly just use query for now as its a prototype. then use session when develop the real thing.